# How to deploy a project Python 3.4/Django 1.9/Django rest framework 3.3 on IIS7

Tags: django, iis-7, django-rest-framework, python-3.4

I have created a project in Django rest framework and able to deploy on Apache 2.2 using mod_wsgi.

Now I need to deploy it on IIS7 (windows 7). I go through a lot of blog but all are telling about python 2.7 and IIS. I didn't get any answer for python 3.4.

I read that I can use FastCgi of IIS to deploy but I really didn't understand, how?

I tried a lot but without success.

Any help?